# How Can I Make A Timer Using String In xCode

Tags: swift, string, xcode, timer, countdowntimer

So I'm trying to make a chess timer. I'm using string to make the 00:00 in a variable called storeTimed. Is there a way possible to make that used an timer to count down from that?

Here's my code:

The part I need help with is the updateTimer() function. Since the storedTime is a string trying to pass as a Int, xCode isn't liking it. I'm honestly not very sure what I could do. Mostly at the else statement, but the whole part in general

```
class ChessTimer: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var playerTimer1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var playerTimer2: UILabel!
    
    var timer = Timer()
    
    var time = 10
    var isTimerRunning = false
    
    var storedTime = "00:00"
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

       if isTimerRunning == false {
           runTimer()
       }
        
        
    }

    @IBAction func restartButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        
        
    }
    
    @IBAction func pausePressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        timer.invalidate()
    }
    
    @IBAction func settingsPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToSettings", sender: self)
        
    }
    
    func runTimer() {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self,selector: (#selector(ChessTimer.updateTimer)),userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
           isTimerRunning = true
       }
    
    @objc func updateTimer() {
        if Int(storedTime) < 1 {
             timer.invalidate()
            playerTimer1.text = "00:00"
            playerTimer2.text = "00:00"
         }
            else {
        Int(storedTime)! -= 1
       playerTimer1.text = prodTimeString(time: TimeInterval(storedTime)!)
        
        }
        
     }
    
    func prodTimeString(time: TimeInterval) -> String {
        let prodMinutes = Int(time) / 60 % 60
        let prodSeconds = Int(time) % 60

        return String(format: "%02d:%02d", prodMinutes, prodSeconds)
    }
    
    
    @IBAction func playerButton1(_ sender: UIButton) {
    }
    
    
    @IBAction func playerButton2(_ sender: UIButton) {
    }
    
    
    @IBAction func unwindToVC1(sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {
        
        
        if let settingsController = sender.source as? SettingsController {
            playerTimer1.text = settingsController.storedTime
            playerTimer2.text = settingsController.storedTime
            
            storedTime = settingsController.storedTime
        
        }
    
   }

}
```

Comment: Do not store time as a string. Time is a number. Store a number, manipulate a number. Covert to an outgoing string only for user interface display.

Comment: @matt I'm not sure how to make it display as a number though. 

Right now I have just the interface done. The clock buttons don't even work. I need to find a way to do transfer the timer to the other clock when one is pressed.

Comment: But that is not what you asked. The question was “Since the storedTime is a string trying to pass as a Int, xCode isn't liking it.” I’m telling you how to approach that.

Comment: @matt How do I manipulate it and convert it?

Comment: @WheexyCodes - all you have to do is change the input parameter in prodTimeString to an Int, and instead of initialising it to - say 02:00, start with a value of 120.  as Matt says, work with a number internally, and only make it a string when you need to display

Comment: @Russell I turned the parameter to an Int, but what about the return value? 

`        return String(format: "%02d:%02d", prodMinutes, prodSeconds)
`
What do i do with that?

Comment: use that in your display, nothing more!  the counter is a number running from 120 (or whatever) down to zero, when it reaches zero, time's up but on every update, you just use that return value as the display

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep things simple, here's the code.  I have removed the functions that aren't relevant to the discussion - non-implemented buttons, etc.,

The simple idea is that you use numbers (Int / Double / whatever) to store variables that you are counting with, and then have helper functions to present the variable in different formats

```
import UIKit

class ChessTimer: UIViewController {
    var timer = Timer()

    var isTimerRunning = false

    var storedTime : Int = 0 // use an integer to store the time

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

       if isTimerRunning == false {
           runTimer()
       }
    }

    func runTimer() {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self,selector: (#selector(ChessTimer.updateTimer)),userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
       isTimerRunning = true
   }

    @objc func updateTimer() {
        // because we're storing the value in an Int, we don't need to convert it here
        storedTime -= 1
        if storedTime < 1 {
            timer.invalidate()
            // use the helper function to format the result for zero time as well as everything else
            // that way, if you ever change it, you only have to change in one place
            playerTimer1.text = prodTimeString(0)
            playerTimer2.text = prodTimeString(0)
         }
         else {
            playerTimer1.text = prodTimeString(storedTime)
          }
     }

    func prodTimeString(_ time: Int) -> String {
        // because there's only one parameter, and it's obvious, add '_' then you don't need the label when you call it
        let prodMinutes = time / 60 % 60
        let prodSeconds = time % 60

        return String(format: "%02d:%02d", prodMinutes, prodSeconds)
    }
}
```